# Yesod: Could not find module `Yesod.Auth.Account'

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm developing a website with scaffolded Yesod (stack) and I have to import **Yesod.Auth.Account** to use internals accounts instead openid or others. But when i try import this module i've this output:

```
/usr/home/giulio/Lavori/karmen/src/Foundation.hs:27:1: error:
    Could not find module `Yesod.Auth.Account'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
27 | import Yesod.Auth.Account
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried to install the module, build, use `stack clean` and `stack build` but
nothing work.

Comment: Have you added the module to your `.cabal` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from the [yesod-auth-account](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-account) package which [doesn't seem to be on Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.7/hoogle?q=yesod-auth-account). This means you must add it to the `extra-deps` stanza of your `stack.yaml` file. [Docs here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps).

Probably something like this:

```
extra-deps:
- yesod-auth-account-1.4.3
```

You may also want to use the `stack solver` command.